# scanf() only sign and number

Tags: c, scanf

I want to get variables *sign* and *number* with scanf().
There is how it should works:

```
 input:
 + 10
 output:
 OK, "sign = +" and "number = 10"
```

```
 input:
 +10
 output:
 Fail!
```

```
 input:
 10
 output:
 Fail!
```

```
 input:
 a
 output:
 Fail!
```

I've tried this solution, but it doesn't worked for me. Especially for inputs: *+10* and *a*

```
 plus='+';
 minus='-';     

 if ( scanf(" %c %d", &sign, &number) != 2 || ((sign != minus) && (sign != plus)) || number < 0 ) 
                {
                printf("Fail!");
                } 
            else {...}
```

Thanks.

Comment: what doesn't work? There is a missing comma between  `&sign`  and `&number`. You better show the actual code.

Comment: "a" is not a number nor it fits your pattern (sign number) so no surprise it prints "Fail!"

Comment: You *want* to use `scanf` or you *need* to use `scanf` for an assignment.  If you are required to use `scanf`, chux solution is very good.  Otherwise, if you want to implement precise semantics, `scanf` is not recommended, you should read the input with `fgets` and parse it in C.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks I want to use scanf and I will take a look at fgets in manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf(" %c %d", &sign &number) != 2` does not work as the format does not *require* a space between the `char` and `int`.  A `" "` matches 0 or more white-space, not a single `' '`.

---

So code needs to look for *sign*, *space* and *number*.

```
char sign[2];
int number;
if (scanf(" %1[+-]%*1[ ]%d", sign, &number) != 2) {
  puts("Fail");
}
```

`" "` Scan and skip optional white-space
`"%1[+-]"`  Scan and save 1 + or -
`"%*1[ ]"` Scan and do not save a space.
`"%d"` Scan white-spaces and then an `int`.

---

Note: Better to use `fgets()`, read the line and then use `sscanf()`.

---

[Edit] More robust solution - it uses `fgets()` as robust solutions do not use `scanf()`.

```
  char buf[80];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    puts("EOF");
  } else {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(buf," %*1[+-]%*1[ ]%*[0-9] %n", &n);
    if (n == 0) {
      puts("Fail - conversion incomplete");
    } else if (buf[n] != '\0') {
      puts("Fail - Extra garbage");
    } else {
      char sign;
      int number;
      sscanf(buf," %c%d", &sign, &number);
      printf("Success %c %d\n",sign, number);
    }
  }
```

`"%n"` Saves the count of characters scanned.

Tip: Appending `%n"` to `int n = 0; ... sscanf(..., "... %n"` to the end of a format is an easy trick to 1) test if scanning was incomplete `if (n == 0)` and  2) test for trailing non-white-space `if (buf[n] != '\0')`

Note: No checks for overflow.

Comment: I believe the OP doesn't want to require a space between the sign and number.

Comment: @CareyGregory The examples in the question are how it *should* work, e.g. "+10" *should* fail.

Comment: Thank you, now it works perfect. I'll test it one more time, but it looks good. Thank you very very much.

Comment: `scanf` cannot do the job reliably:  You very shrewd proposal will fail to fail on `+ +10`,  `+ -10`, `- +10`, `- -10`... not to mention extra spaces: should they be ignored or rejected?

Comment: @chqrlie True.  OP's examples and direction left a lot of interpretation.  I'll post a more pedantic one too.

Comment: `+ +10` is OK and for `+ -10` I will add `|| number<0` to the if() construction. Extra spaces should be ignored, I just want have at least one space between + and 10.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten a comma here:

```
scanf(" %c %d", &sign &number)
```

Also the space is both redundant and erroneous.
It should be

```
scanf(" %c%d", &sign, &number)
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the comma when a was writing this post. But your code works only for "+ 10", for "a" the program waiting for another input.

Comment: Sorry, I just pointed the easy mistakes.  If you want to validate the input, read the line with `fgets` and parse it with `sscanf` or write the simple logic in C, `scanf` and friends are cumbersome, error prone and inefficient.