# C input char and int separated by whitespace

Tags: c

I need to parse input like this: "+ 704"
Into: switcher = "+" and c = 749
I got this:

```
scanf("%c %d", &switcher, &c);
```

This does not work.
Scanf returns 1 instead of 2, c = 4196080 and `printf("%c", switcher)` prints a newline.
What am i missing?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660753/scanf-only-sign-and-number

Comment: Thanks, didn't stumble upon that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, there's a newline waiting on the buffer. To get rid of it, simply add one space to the beginning of your formatting string.

```
scanf(" %c %d", &switcher, &c);
```